# Facebook Graph API filter application by id

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api

I've been trying to migrate my app from FQL to GRAPH API but I'm finding it more difficult than expected. I want to filter the posts by application ID. This is, I want to list all the posts made using my application. The FQL query is working fine but somehow I cannot replicate it on the GRAPH API.

My FQL query is the following:

```
    fql?q=SELECT post_id, actor_id, message, app_id, attribution FROM stream WHERE source_id = me() AND app_id = 'XXXXXXXXXXX'
```

Many thanks all!

Answer (score 1):

I think you'll have a hard time doing what you want after April 30th 2015, because you'll need the `read_stream` permission approved by Facebook, which is quite unlikely.

Anyway, with the pure Graph API, you can only filter on some (FB) app ids, as described in

- https://developers.facebook.com/docs/graph-api/reference/v2.2/user/feed/#read

Sample call:

```
GET /me/feed?filter=pp
```

would give you only page posts for example.